# "The type reference cannot find a public type..." error in WPF Custom Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I'm trying my first WPF custom control. I've hardly done anything and it won't compile. I get an error in my generic.xaml that says, "The type reference cannot find a public type named 'Filmstrip'. Line 7 Position 50 (Line 7 is the Style start tag)

Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespaces:Unicorn.Controls">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Filmstrip}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Filmstrip}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Filmstrip.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Unicorn.Controls
{
    public class Filmstrip : Control
    {
        static Filmstrip()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Filmstrip), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Filmstrip)));
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you be lacking an assembly specification in the `xmlns:local` declaration?

Comment: The xaml is in the same assembly as the custom control class.

Comment: Have you tried using a non-static public constructor?

Comment: Am i right in assuming that this prevents compilation rather than being just a malinformed warning?

Comment: @Hasanain: That should affect this at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clr-namespaces:Unicorn.Controls` should be `clr-namespace:Unicorn.Controls`. Singular, not plural.

Comment: In my case the problem was that an unnecessary ";assembly=<this_assembly's_name>" had been appended to the end of the namespace string by some tool or another, but the result was the same.

Answer (score 3):

It appears you have a syntax error in your xaml.  The following line:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespaces:Unicorn.Controls"
```

should be

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Unicorn.Controls"
```

Also, unless this is the assembly you are working in don't forget to use the assembly parameter to reference other assemblies.